# Add js to a selector dropdown in order to get userinput

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding and I am currently working on an assignment. I basically need to build a very basic webpage in which I can ask questions to users and then suggest a vacation destination using their answers.

I used a select dropdown box with options for the user. I am now on the js part and I cannot figure out how to get their input.

this is my code for one of the boxes:

```
<div class="container">
       <h1>Let's find your ideal vacation getaway!</h1>
       <div id="userinput">
         <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="question1">1.What is your favorite cuisine?</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option></option>
              <option>Mexican</option>
              <option>Italian</option>
              <option>Indian</option>
              <option>Caribbean</option>
            </select>
```

My question is, what function do I utilize to get their answers, thus allowing me to use branching to generate results. I am sorry if this is confusing, like I said, I am very new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a school assignment then this should have been covered in class; I'd suggest - again, *if this is a school assignment* - working with your peers, or asking for direction from your tutor. Beyond that you need to show us how far you got, what attempts did you make, what results did that have? What went wrong, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi David , this is a class assignment that only requires us to use text boxes and not dropdown list. I wanted to go the extra mile and challenge myself, therefore I opted for the dropdown list. I think I went too far ahead for what we have done in class. I am only in an intro class to decide whether I want to pursue this or not. –

Comment: this was my attempt:$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#userinput").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var number1 = $("#question1").val();
    var number2 = $("#question2").val();
    var number3 = $("#question3").val();
    var number4 = $("#question4").val();
    var number5 = $("#question5").val();
    var result;
        if (number1 === "Mexican" && number2 === "Sunshine all day long") {
        document.write('<h1>Mexico</h1>');

    } 
    $("#output").text(result);

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in both HTML and JS part. In HTML add `value` attribute and assign a value to each of the options. Also add an `onchange` event handler which will be fired on change of options from drop-down.

Assign an `id` to the `select` element. Use [**selectedIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) to get index of selected item

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control" onChange="getSelected()" id="selDesc">
              <option value="0"> Select a destination</option>
              <option value="1">Mexican</option>
              <option value="2">Italian</option>
              <option value="3">Indian</option>
              <option value="4">Caribbean</option>
            </select>
```

**JS**

```
function getSelected(){
var getValue =document.getElementById("selDesc").selectedIndex;
alert(getValue);

}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zqhhg6r5/)

Answer (score 0):

**Make changes in Html Code means give the id on select tag**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Let's find your ideal vacation getaway!</h1>
    <div id="userinput">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="question1">1.What is your favorite cuisine?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="country">
                    <option value="0" selected> --Select--</option>
                   <option value="1">Mexican</option>
                   <option value="2">Italian</option>
                   <option value="3">Indian</option>
                   <option value="4">Caribbean</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS use Jquery

```
        $("#country").change(function (e) {                
            alert($(this).val());
        })
```